# Android ADB simulate a long tap followed by a swipe

Tags: android, adb

I'm testing a feature and here's what i need to do:

In order to be activated ( and remain activated ) i need to long press on it and in order for me to cancel it, while holding the tap i need to swipe to the left.

So the question: is there any way that i can long tap and while the tap is still ongoing, swipe to the left using ADB commands?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Upon further inspection, i found a neat workaround. Instead of tap followed by swipe, i just used a really slow swipe.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `adb shell sendevent` or record full process with http://fattuba.com/android-record-and-playback/

Comment: Instead of posting links as answer add some text to explanation how this answer help to OP in fixing current issue.Thanks